# How to make image view fill out all the screen in Swift in second storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to create a second Storyboard. I want it to be similar to the first Storyboard background. I insert UIImageView and fit it all the page, however, why it is not fitting the entire page as shown in the image below:

[image: see image]

Comment: Looks like the view controller itself isn't presented full screen, not the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the presentation of ViewController in storyBoard.

[image]